# GL_INVALID_ENUM/GL_INVALID_OPERATION after OpenGL 3.1 context creation

Tags: c++, opengl

I have another hopefully not THAT stupid question- I wanted to clean up some old code I updated from OpenGL1.3 to 3.1. So I changed now in a final step the context creation to something like this (own code below):
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial:_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29

I am using GLEW 1.13.0 and if I do only glewInit additionally to the old context creation everything works fine, but after switching to a pure 3.1 context:

```
glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT,GL_NICEST); is giving me GL_INVALID_ENUM
glAlphaFunc( GL_GREATER, 0.5 ); is giving me GL_INVALID_OPERATION
glDisable( GL_ALPHA_TEST ); is giving me GL_INVALID_ENUM
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE); is giving me GL_INVALID_ENUM
```

now from what I read none of these is deprecated in OpenGL3.1 - What did I miss?

It currently looks like this:

```
hWnd = (HWND)GetWindow();
hDC = GetDC( hWnd );

INT DesiredColorBits   = 32;
INT DesiredStencilBits = 8;
INT DesiredDepthBits   = 24;

PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
pfd.nVersion = 1;
pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,
pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
pfd.cColorBits = DesiredColorBits;
pfd.cDepthBits = DesiredDepthBits;
pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
pfd.cStencilBits = DesiredStencilBits;

INT nPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat( hDC, &pfd );
printf("Using pixel format %i", nPixelFormat);
if (!SetPixelFormat( hDC, nPixelFormat, &pfd ))
    return 0;

hRC = wglCreateContext( hDC );
wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);

//init glew
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (GLEW_OK != err)
     return 0;

INT MajorVersion=3;
INT MinorVersion=1;

if (WGLEW_ARB_create_context && WGLEW_ARB_pixel_format)
{
    memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
    pfd.nSize= sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion   = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags    = PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cDepthBits = 24;
    pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

    const INT iPixelFormatAttribList[] =
    {
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, GL_TRUE,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, DesiredColorBits,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, DesiredDepthBits,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, DesiredStencilBits,
        0 // End of attributes list
    };
    INT iContextAttribs[] =
    {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, MajorVersion,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, MinorVersion,
        WGL_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB,
        0 // End of attributes list
    };

    INT iPixelFormat, iNumFormats;
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(hDC, iPixelFormatAttribList, NULL, 1, &iPixelFormat, (UINT*)&iNumFormats);

    // pfd oldstyle crap...
    if (!SetPixelFormat(hDC, iPixelFormat, &pfd))
        return 0;

    hRC = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(hDC, 0, iContextAttribs);
}

if(hRC) 
{
    printf("GL_VENDOR     : %s", glGetString(GL_VENDOR));
    printf("GL_RENDERER   : %s", glGetString(GL_RENDERER));
    printf("GL_VERSION    : %s", glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf("GLEW Version  : %s", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC);
}
else 
    return 0;
```

I stripped out the code, so sorry if I missed something, but the context is initialized and I am getting:

```
Using pixel format 9
GL_VENDOR     : NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER   : GeForce GT 740M/PCIe/SSE2
GL_VERSION    : 4.4.0
GLEW Version  : 1.13.0
```

The first part in the code initializes the old style context in order to get GLEW initialized and while I am a bit unsure about the PFD part in the 3.1 creation (although many examples show it like this). Nevertheless I tried a few different variants from different examples and tutorials and it always resulted in the GL_INVALID_OPERATION and GL_INVALID_ENUM when trying to set the states above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT` isn't in core anymore, and neither it was in 3.1. Refer to [the OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glHint) for details, but allowed enums in 3.1 (and staying the same up to 4.5) are:

- `GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT`
- `GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT`
- `GL_TEXTURE_COMPRESSION_HINT`
- `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT`

That being said, don't bother with creating 3.1 contexts. If you can, go for 4.4/4.5, if you want to support previous generation, 3.3 is the reasonable minimum.

Comment: ok, so I missed the GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT - that's already good to know - but unfortunately doesn't explain the rest, like glAlphaFunc( GL_GREATER, 0.5 ); and glDisable( GL_ALPHA_TEST ); - which I later need again and 3.1 I just chose for now to have the absolute minimum version I need to run my updated code. Oh and using 3.3 doesn't change this problem unfortunately too :(.

Comment: @Gnampf `AlphaFunc` and `ALPHA_TEST` are deprecated since 3.0 (and removed in 4) - if you looked closer, you've noticed that your GPU created a 4.4 context for you anyway. Using 3.3/4.4 won't solve the problem directly, but 3.3 gives you more tools to solve it.

Comment: Oh damn. Wondering why I didn't find that this was removed. Thanks, now I know what to work out yet.